# invalid literal for int() with base 10 in functional programming

Tags: python

Here is the task:

> **Input format**
>
> Enter the number N, and then N numbers.
>
> **Output format**
>
> Print `True` if among the entered numbers there is at least one zero, or `False` otherwise.

Here is my code:

```
print(any(map(lambda x: x == 0, map(int, input().split()), range(int(input())))))
```

Got this error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-aeca5129eae6> in <module>
----> 1 print(any(map(lambda x: x == 0, map(int, input().split()), range(int(input())))))

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2 0 3'
```

using this input:

```
3
2 0 3
```

Could you please explain me why?

Comment: What input are you providing?

Comment: for example:
3
2 0 3
(2 0 3 is a new line, not sure if you can see it from the comments)

Comment: @Vika Please [edit] the question to add that, as well as the full error message. See [mre] for reference. BTW welcome to SO! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want advice.

Comment: does it have to be all one line? It would be easier to read and debug if you broke it up.

Comment: the full error is the next:
3
2 0 3
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-aeca5129eae6> in <module>
----> 1 print(any(map(lambda x: x == 0, map(int, input().split()), range(int(input())))))

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2 0 3'

Comment: @wjandrea yeah, it has to be on one line due to the task)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error message. The formatting also looks broken.

Comment: @AMC I did, both in comments and in the question itself

Answer (score 2):

Based on your sample input, `range(int(input()))` errors because "2 0 3" is not a valid int. 
Try this:

```py
input() # skip 1st line because its not needed
print(any(map(lambda x: x == 0, map(int, input().split()))))
```

Input:

```
3
2 0 3
```

Comment: got the error "not functional enough" in the testing system, so, I suppose I have tu use range somehow to make all of this in one line

Comment: @VikaGavrilova What are you using, that determines how "functional" the code is? It seems like it could get rather frustrating.

Comment: @AMC it is a testing system on Coursera, so I don't know how they check, however, I tried this code:

print(any(map(lambda x: x == 0, (lambda y: map(int, input().split()))(int(input())))))


but it fails on the 4th test (wrong answer), but they don't give me the input they are using for the test, so I have no idea, why the answer is wrong and where that weak place is in the code